# React Undefined property

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a little application but I encountered a problem. 
What I'm doing is that when login is successful, the server gives a web token and I store the token inside `sessionStorage` in order to check that every component is accessible. 
However, if I use the below code, the component invokes an undefined error. I thought the below code is the correct to way to check undefined property.

```
 render() {
        const {isLogin} = this.state;
        if(isLogin){
            return (
                <Redirect to={{
                    pathname: '/home',
                    state: {token: sessionStorage.getItem('secretKey')}
                }}
                />
               )
           }
--------------------------------------------
       class Home extends React.Component{
         render(){
          if(!this.props.location.state.token){
            return(
            <Redirect to="/" />
           )
         }
            return <h1>Home</h1>
         }
        }
```

Let me explain once again.
If the user succeeds to login, the component redirect to the "Home" component and the Home component check if the `this.props.location.state.token` is defined. If it is undefined, the Home component redirects to the login component.

Answer (score 0):

```
token: sessionStorage.getItem('secretKey')}||"" }}
```

What about use`||` to make sure token is not undefined?